# I see the command `tmux send-keys` but is there a way to send the output to adjacent pane

Tags: tmux

In a tmux session I am trying to find out if there is a quick way to send some outputs from one pane to the parallel pane.

For instance if I am in left pane (say 0.0) and want to send the output of the `pwd` command to the right pane (say 0.1).  Is there a quick way to do this.

Apologize in advance if this has an answer but googled for way to long without getting anything but `tmux send-keys -t right 'some text'`.

Instead I want to display the output in adjacent pane, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Now that I have come back after some time and read my question I see that it might be not as simple as I thought.  I am better of typing what I want or something like this but I'd be probably typing more,  `pwd1=$(pwd); tmux send-keys -t right 'cd '$pwd1`.  But if there is some thing I would learn here I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to display the output in adjacent pane

If you know the file name of the terminal connected to the other pane (what `tty` prints), you can write to it. Example:

```
pwd >/dev/pts/1
```

But this only *displays* characters there; there is no interaction with whatever program runs in the pane. You used the word "display" but I'm not sure this is what you want. The solution works without tmux as well.

---

If you want to send the output to the stdin of some command you're about to invoke in another pane, then use a named pipe:

```
mkfifo foo
pwd >foo
```

Now go to another shell (another pane) and read from `foo`:

```
<foo whatever
```

This also doesn't rely on tmux.

---

If you want to paste the output in another pane (e.g. to make it a fragment of a new command in a shell there):

1. Invoke `pwd` normally in the source pane.
2. Go into copy mode and copy the output. With mouse support it's enough to hold the left mouse button and drag. After you release the button, the selected text is stored in a buffer automatically.
3. To to the target pane.
4. Paste the stored text with `paste-buffer` (<kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> by default).